# Python Fabric Sudo su - user

Tags: python, sudo, fabric

I currently do the following from the command line:

```
$ ssh myuser@remote-server 
password:
[myuser@remote-server ~]$ sudo su - dev_user
[dev_user@remote-server ~]$ whoami
dev_user
[dev_user@remote-server ~]$
```

No permission issue.

The myuser has enough permission to do what typed above, but it does not have permission to do `sudo su -c whoami dev_user`

I tried the following code

```
from fabric import Connection, task
 
@task
def abcd(ctx):
    sudo_pass = getpass.getpass("What's your sudo password?")
    config = Config(overrides={'sudo': {'password': sudo_pass}})
    with Connection('dev-server', user='myuser', connect_kwargs={"password": sudo_pass}, config=config) as c:
        c.sudo('/bin/bash -l -c whoami', user='dev_user')
```

I get the following output:

```
fab abcd
What's your sudo password?
[sudo] password: Sorry, user myuser is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash -l -c whoami' as dev_user on dev-server.
```

Is there a way to get Fabric to do what I did from the command line?

Editing the `sudoers` file is not an option.

The remote server is Linux RH 7.6.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use `sudo` with a `user=` argument, to use sudo to switch to another user, just like you are doing in the shell:

```
from  fabric import Connection

c = Connection('host')
c.sudo('/bin/bash -l -c whoami', user='dev_user')
```

> **sudo** accepts additional `user` and `group` arguments, which are passed to sudo and allow you to run as some user and/or group other than root. On most systems, the sudo program can take a string username/group or an integer userid/groupid (uid/gid); `user` and `group` may likewise be strings or integers.

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/api/core/operations.html?highlight=sudo#fabric.operations.sudo

The above solution will only work if you can run `sudo` without entering your password. If your account, `myuser` requires a password to run `sudo`, then you can prompt for that password, and pass it to `fabric`'s config:

```
import getpass
from fabric import Connection, Config

sudo_pass = getpass.getpass("What's your sudo password?")
config = Config(overrides={'sudo': {'password': sudo_pass}})
c = Connection('host', config=config)

c.sudo('/bin/bash -l -c whoami', user='dev_user')
```

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.3/getting-started.html#the-sudo-helper

One final idea:

```
from  fabric import Connection, Config

config = Config(overrides={'sudo': {'user': 'sudo_user'}})
c = Connection('host', config=config)

c.sudo('whoami')
```

Note that no sudo password is provided in this case, but a `user` is, in the `Config` setup. And `c.sudo` is changed back to a simple `c.sudo('whoami')`. This *should* be interpreted as `sudo su - sudo_user` by Fabric.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188453/discussion-on-answer-by-nikolas-stevenson-molnar-python-fabric-sudo-su-user). Please [edit] any relevant information into the answer.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks, I didn't know about chat.

Comment: OK @CodyGray. Sorry about that. One last comment. doing the follow seems to have worked, but it looks very limited. c.run('echo "whoami" | sudo su - dev_user')

Answer (score 2):

The following works:

```
c.run("echo 'whoami' | sudo su - dev_user")
c.run("echo 'cd /some/directory && ./somescript.sh' | sudo su - dev_user")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this :

```
conn.run("sudo su root -c 'cd /some/directory && ls -la && ./somescript.sh'")
```

Answer (score -2):

With `paython 3x` and `fabric 2.4.0` you could use it like this

install fabric using pip `pip3 install fabric>=2.4.0`

```
from fabric import Connection as connection, task

@task
def executeTask(ctx):
    with connection(host=dev_server, user=myuser) as c:
         c.run('sudo su - dev_user')
```

Place this code in a file called fabfile.py and run it by executing this command from your command-line `fab executeTask`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but after executing, it just hangs there waiting for me to type in further commands. My goal was to do more c.run calls after the c.run('sudo su - dev_user'), such as c.run('whoami') and it would show the dev_user. i.e. I would like to run the c.run function as a dev_user after sudo-ing to it. Would that be possible?